# what collation of mysql that distinguish utf8 character

Tags: mysql

I want a character set that distinguish utf8 character

I want **select ('thanh'='thành')** return 0 instead of 1.

I have tried utf8_unicode_ci, utf8_general_ci, utf8_bin, utf8_vietnamese_ci. But all of them return 1 for above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CAST(...) COLLATE utf8_bin.

**Query**

```
SELECT CAST('thanh' AS CHAR) COLLATE utf8_bin = CAST('thành' AS CHAR) COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

**Result**

```
CAST('thanh' AS CHAR) COLLATE utf8_bin = CAST('thành' AS CHAR) COLLATE utf8_bin  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                 0
```